# Is uint16_t and uint32_t interrupt safe in Cortex M architecture?

Tags: interrupt, cortex-m

I am working on some embedded stuff. I had multiple interrupts possibly working on same data and so I was wondering if `uint16_t` and `uint32_t` data types are interrupt safe.

If interrupt is working a `uint16/32_t` data and is halfway interrupted by another interrupt that is trying to read this data, it will see corrupted data. Is this a possible scenario?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cortex-M processors do not corrupt and give your data undefined value. The value will always be deterministic. However, there are many conditions that affect the value of the data in case of interrupts. The `uint16/32_t` data can be located in the memory, or only inside the processor registers. If in memory, it can be 16/32-bit aligned or not 16/32-bit aligned. The processor, e.g. M0 or M4, and the operation performed on the data, e.g. add or multiply, also matter. All of those will determine whether the instruction used to process the data is atomic or not.

You can find more details in this [discussion](https://community.arm.com/developer/ip-products/processors/f/cortex-m-forum/11166/interruptible-instructions-on-cortex-m4) and [this](https://community.arm.com/developer/ip-products/processors/f/cortex-a-forum/4201/c-c-atomic-operation-on-arm9-and-arm-cortex-m4) answered by Joseph Yiu.

Generally speaking, if the instruction is atomic (single execution cycle), the interrupt cannot disturb the data operation. However, at your C code level, `uint16/32_t` data operation may take more than 1 instruction. Therefore, it is hard to guarantee that the program runs as expected. This also applies to `uint8_t` data. You may wish to disable interrupts before working on the shared data and enable interrupts afterwards. The technique is covered well in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49409910/11634446) (look at point 2).

Answer (score 2):

To expand on the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56568402/is-uint16-t-and-uint32-t-interrupt-safe-in-cortex-m-architecture/56575154#56575154) from @DinhQC, all single-result instructions on 16- and 32-bit data types are 'atomic' with respect to interrupts on the Cortex-M as long as the data is properly aligned (and you have to try quite hard to get the C compiler to give you unaligned data, because unaligned accesses are slow and need special treatment).  Multiple-result operations like `LDM` and `STM` can be interrupted and resumed, on most implementations, but the integrity of each individual 32-bit transfer within the `LDM` or `STM` is guaranteed.

The important thing is to understand whether the operations you're performing are single instructions at the machine level or not.  If you're incrementing a shared variable, for example, this will take three instructions: a read, a modify, and a write.  If an interrupt occurs in between the read and the write, and the interrupt service routine modifies the same variable, this modification will be overwritten when the ISR returns.

The safe way to go is to use some kind of hardware-supported mechanism to enforce atomicity or mutual exclusion over your shared data.  There are more powerful, more flexible and faster approaches to mutual exclusion on the Cortex-M than disabling and re-enabling interrupts, though, notably the `STREX` and `LDREX` instructions (which are available in C too).  Take a look at [my answer to this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51795537/critical-sections-in-arm/51797599#51797599) for more information.